# .htaccess - Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make the following rewrite:

```
http://example.com/folder1/folder3/index.html
```

to:

```
http://example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/index.html
```

for that I've tried the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^folder1/folder2/.*$
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*)$ /folder1/folder2/$1 [L]
```

But I get: `Internal Server Error`

In the other hand, if I do an experiment (just for testing) like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^folder1/folder2/.*$
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*)$ /kkk/folder2/$1 [L]
```

Then the rewrite:

```
http://example.com/folder1/folder3/index.html
```

to:

```
http://example.com/kkk/folder2/folder3/index.html
```

works. But I need the first rewrite.

Any idea on how to solve this?

**[edited word "redirection" -> word "rewrite"]**

**[edited to add the error.log content]**

On the following jsbin you have the error.log content:

http://jsbin.com/fajohugase/1/edit?output

Comment: Is there a .htaccess in `/folder1/` as well?

Answer (score 0):

The URI in [`REQUEST_URI`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/expr#vars) variable contains the leading `/` as it is the path part of your URL. So, when you're using the `!^folder1` condition, it fails to match, causing an infinite loop.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/folder2/
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*)$ /folder1/folder2/$1 [L]
```

As to your *redirection*, you are not actually redirecting the client; but merely internally rewriting the URL to include `/folder2` in it. For a redirect, you'll need the `R` flag.

Comment: I did the changes above (I double checked) and I'm still getting the "Internal Server Error". About the redirection, you was right, what I need is a rewrite and not a redirection, so I won't use the R flag.

Comment: @nightclub You have some other rewrites, which are adding the `example.com` in your internal redirects, causing an infinite loop.